# How to filter results by their associations when using PG search gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, pg, pg-search

I am using PG search gem in my Rails app. Say I get a set of articles in my controller:

```
@articles = Article.search(params[:search]).with_pg_search_highlight
```

the problem with PG search here is that I get back an array, instead of AR object. So now I cannot do something like

```
@research_articles = @articles.where(category: 'research')
```

Because I will get a

```
undefined method `where' for Array
```

Now I can make several queries from that one action, but what would be a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about changing the chain?

```
@articles = Article.where(category: 'research').search(params[:search]).with_pg_search_highlight
```

EDIT:

A way without making 2 queries would be:

```
@found_articles = Article.search(params[:search]).with_pg_search_highlight
@research_articles = @found_articles.select { |article| article.category == "research" }
```

Comment: yeah, the problem is that I need to get all results and filter after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

pg_search gem provides pg_search_scope.

See the doc https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#pg_search_scope

You can also chain where condition with pg_search_scope.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should define a scope (or even simple getter would be enough here) and reuse it:

```
def simple_search
  pure = Article.search(params[:search])
  (block_given? ? yield(pure) : pure).with_pg_search_highlight
end
```

And then:

```
@articles = simple_search
@research_articles = simple_search { |ss| ss.where(category: 'research') }
```

Comment: How would it be different from articles = Article.search(params[:search]).with_pg_search_highlight; research_articles = Article.where(category: 'research').search(params[:search]).with_pg_search_highlight

Comment: It won't, but it might help to DRY for 50 different searches. Plus the intent is more clear.